# UITextField with inputView showing UIPickerView... how to turn off translucency in IOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uitextfield

We have a tab bar.  In one of the controllers, we have a UITextField.  Clicking on that brings up a picker, using the inputView field of the UITextField.  My team likes the look of that on iOS 6, but on iOS 7 they see the blurred background and tab bar coming through.  Can I turn off that translucency, and where do I need to do that?

```
self.termsPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 43, 320, 480)];
self.termsPickerView.delegate = self;
self.termsPickerView.dataSource = self;
[self.termsPickerView setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
self.termTextField.inputView = self.termsPickerView ;
self.termTextField.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 2):

`UIPickerView` in iOS 7.0 is translucent by default and that is the nature, and like all other views, is simple a background color controlling the color.

So to fix your problem you could do,

```
self.pickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

The apple documentation doesn't show any means of turning this transparency off.

Answer (score 0):

```
tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;
```